# Changing text after importing svg (exported via matplotlib) in Illustrator

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, adobe-illustrator

I am using matplotlib (Python 3.8) to export my figures as svg. When importing those figures into Adobe Illustrator (CC 2018/22.1), the text is split up per letter, i.e. the letters in "Irradiance" (see pic) are all editable, but I can only edit one letter at a time, which is inconvenient. The numbers (10-70 in the image) are however exported as one text item and are not split up.

Additionally, I get the following error message: "The document uses fonts which are not available". The text is however imported after I exit the dialog box, in the font that I want. Sometimes I get this error, but not always...

How can I export svg files that have completely editable text?

***Error message***

[image]

***Screenshot of figure in Adobe Illustrator***

[image]

***Code for exporting svg's using*** `rcParams`

This block of code is at the start of my script:

```
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Open Sans'
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
```

Then I save the figure using:
`fig.savefig(Directory + 'my_figure.svg', transparent=True)`

Comment: It's not a proper answer but anyway, there is the script for Illustrator that can join a selected text objects into one text frame. I'm using one of the variants of such script all the time exactly for such cases. https://ajarproductions.com/blog/2008/11/23/merge-text-extension-for-illustrator/

Comment: Here is the script (Join Text Frame) I'm using for many years: https://kelsocartography.com/scripts/#john

Comment: Hypothetically the script can be modified to make it to find all text objects and join them whenever their Y-coordinates are identical and differences between X-coordinates less than the width of a couple of characters. Though the question looks abandoned.